# How do I extract a part of a string and cast it into an integer?

Tags: sql, oracle, obiee

For Example - If I have a string as mentioned below :-

Summary: Start Volume (monthly) = 2 End Volume (monthly) = 0 Volume Reduction (year) = 13 Efficiency Gains = 100 Log: 09/13/2017

I just want to show the value of Volume Reduction in a column. What query should I write?

Comment: could you explain more exactly what you're going to approach?
which the RDBMS you're using?

Comment: I am trying to use this in a OBIEE Tool. I want to write a sql query for that.

Comment: so tagging oracle would be very nice ;-)

Comment: If you just want to show the Volume Reduction, just write "SELECT VolumeReduction FROM yourtable"

Comment: you want just the '13' in this ex??

Comment: yes I just want '13'

Comment: please read: "How to write a SELECT query"
https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_select.asp

Comment: I can't Select VolumeReduction From table. I am trying to read the value from a string present in the column.

Comment: @SanjuktaGhosh please specify the string from which you want to read the data or value .

Comment: I have already given the string in the example. Please check above

Comment: "Summary: Start Volume (monthly) = 2 End Volume (monthly) = 0 Volume Reduction (year) = 13 Efficiency Gains = 100 Log: 09/13/2017" This is the string guys.

Comment: Yupp that one @Yogesh

Comment: @SanjuktaGhosh whats wrong with current answer ?

Comment: In OBIEE one does NOT "write SQL" but you work with models. If you start writing SQL you're already using the tool totally wrong and better should be using something else...like Notepad.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one

```
SELECT SUBSTR(COL,S1,INSTR(COL,' ',S1)-S1) X
FROM  (SELECT COL, INSTR( COL, 'Volume Reduction (year) = ',1)+LEN('Volume Reduction (year) = ') AS S1
       FROM (SELECT 'Summary: Start Volume (monthly) = 2 End Volume (monthly) = 0 Volume Reduction (year) = 13 Efficiency Gains = 100 Log: 09/13/2017' AS COL 
             FROM DUAL) A
        ) B;
```

Output:

```
X
13
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one :

```
DECLARE @DATA VARCHAR(256);
DECLARE @DATA1 VARCHAR(256);

SET @DATA = 'Summary: Start Volume (monthly) = 2 End Volume (monthly) = 0 Volume Reduction (year) = 13 Efficiency Gains = 100 Log: 09/13/2017'

SELECT @DATA1 = RIGHT(@DATA,LEN(@DATA)-CHARINDEX(' 13',@DATA))

SELECT SUBSTRING(@DATA1, PATINDEX('%[1-9]%', @DATA1), LEN(120)) AS DATA
```